# GCC fails to report an ill-formed constexpr lambda call

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, constexpr, avr-gcc

Below are two test-cases for Undefined Behaviour, expressed as IIFE (Immediately Called Lambda-Axpression):

```
constexpr auto test3 = []{
    int* p{};
    {   
        int x{};
        p = &x;
    }
    return *p; // Undefined Behaviour
}(); // IIFE

constexpr auto test4 = []{
    int x = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
    int y = -x;  // Undefined Behaviour
    return y;
}();

int main() {}
```

When compiled with GCC trunk, `test4` is correctly rejected as it exhibs Undefined Behaviour in a `constexpr`. On the other hand `test3` is accepted.

Is GCC right to accept `test3`?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 The standard requires that ALL UB in a constexpr be diagnosed.

Comment: @NathanOliver oh thanks. thats how I learn, I make mistakes ;)

Comment: Yep.  Looks like a GCC bug

Comment: I will report it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is GCC right to accept test3?

No, this is a GCC bug. I just reported it as [bug #93389](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=93389).

Comment: Thank you for streamlining to question and the answer!